# Parse ajax HTML response, and append result

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, regex

i get condition where i need to request page with ajax. and i get HTML as result. parse those HTML result, and append parsed HTML content into current page.

let say this HTML content is the one requested :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div id="main">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://script.com/js/script.js"></script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

How to parse `#main`id selector (including javascript text) than append it on part of current HTML.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: requestedurl,
    type : "POST",
    dataType : "text",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(jQuery(data).find("#main"));
        // than append
    }
});
```

is it better to not to parse using jquery, but regex? thank you very much for help.

ps : i try to load result using jquery, i get text node content, etc. unfortunately i don't know how to parse it. :(

Comment: _"is it better to not to parse using jquery, but regex?"_ Absolutely not. Use jQuery. Have you tried `jQuery(data).find("#main").appendTo("body");`

Comment: then how to do that? when i load those html, i get only text node content, and javascript tag is gone :(

Answer (score 1):

change your dataType from "text" to "html"

Comment: i empty object when try to execute `console.log(jQuery(data).find("#main"));` while dataType is HTML :(

Comment: conosle.log( $(data) ) and see what you get. It sounds like your html is wrong. If #main is the root element then there is no need for .find()

Comment: result begin from <html> tag until </html> tag. result when i do loging is text node. i don't know what is this text node.

Answer (score 1):

You should skip the textnode.

I got in the console `[
Text, <div id=​"main">​</div>​, <script type=​"text/​javascript" src=​"http:​/​/​script.com/​js/​script.js"></script>​, Text]`

so just get `jquery(data)[1]`

I tried the same thing as you with in test.html :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div id="main">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://script.com/js/script.js"></script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and in another file

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery.ajax({
        url: './test.html',
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "html",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(jQuery(data)[1]); //Then i got the main div
            // than append
        }
    });
   });
    </script>
```

Comment: You might need to get `jQuery(data)[2]` too to append. Because it's the script that was inside the main div.

Comment: well, its great. but i cannot find any <script> tag on the result.

Comment: What does `console.log(jQuery(data))` outputs to the console, exactly ? I used the same html code as the one you provided so it's weird we don't have the same results