# Parsing an AJAX result with jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I know that many topics exist about that, but I didn't find a solution to my issue.
I make an AJAX request, and I'd like to parse the result, and inject it in a table in my page.

```
$.ajax( {
        type    :   "GET",
        url     :   "http://keyserver.gingerbear.net/pks/lookup?",
        data    :   "search=john.smith@gmail.com&fingerprint=on&op=index",
        dataType:   "html",
        success :   function(resultat){
                        $(resultat).ready(function() {
                                $('pre',$(resultat).html()).each(function(){
                                var htmlString = $(this).html();
                                console.log("Key ID : "+/0x[a-z0-9]{16}/i.exec(htmlString));
                                console.log("User : "+$(this).find('a:eq(1)').text());
                                console.log("Bits : "+/[0-9]{4}[RD]/.exec(htmlString));
                                console.log("Data : "+/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/.exec(htmlString));
                                console.log("Fingerprint : "+/Fingerprint=(.*)/.exec(htmlString));
                                });
                        });
                    },
        // Blabla
    } );
```

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362126/parse-ajax-html-response-and-append-result) the beginning of a solution. For example I can do console.log($(resultat).find('a')) and I have the content of the first  , but console.log($(resultat).find('pre')) doesn't work...

Comment: Can you give a sample value for `reultat`?

Comment: Yes, resultat contains the content of this page, in my example : keyserver.gingerbear.net/pks/lookup?search=john.smith@gmail.com&fingerprint=on&op=index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should use `jQuery` [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load the external content into an element.

To answer your question, you can't use `find` to look for the `pre` tag when `$(this)` represents the element you're searching for (the `pre` in this case). You can however search for a parent element to the `pre` and then use `.find` from the parent element.

```
var parent = $(this).closest("#parentDiv");
var preChild = parent.find("pre").first();
```

Comment: Woohooo ! With the load function I can parse the result indeed and display it in the console ! Now I have to build my table with the result and inject it in the DOM instead of the brut content.